# CSS Fixed Size Header: Floating Contact Info to the Right

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a basic fixed width header. The company name should be to the far left of the header and the contact info should be on the far right of the header.

I floated the contact info to the right but it is now appearing outside of the header. I don't know what I am doing wrong?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wXh7P/

**CSS**

```
#header {
    width: 960px;
    background-color: #CCC;
    margin: 40px auto 0px auto;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-top-right-radius: 25px;
    border-top-left-radius: 25px;
}
.contact {
    text-align: right;
    float: right;
    width: 500px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="header">
<h1>Acme, Inc.</h1>
<p class="contact">Serving XYZ Since 2002<br />
Service 1, Service 2, Service 3, Service 4 and Service 5</p>
<p class="contact">(555) 555-5555</p>
<p class="contact">7438 Example Street<br />
Anytown, CA 55555</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it's because the h1 takes up all the space in the header

```
#header h1{
 display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should apply `overflow:auto` to the `header` element to make it display the floated inner content as now it doesn't exist in the document flow so it can't expand parent's size.

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/wXh7P/2/)

Answer (score 1):

h# elements are block level elements and will therefore default to taking up the full width and push down your other content. Setting the `display: inline-block;` will fix this. See my update to your Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mifi79/wXh7P/4/